# Reference to a non-shared member requires an object reference for showing/hiding forms

Tags: vb.net, winforms

I have 3 forms, the form2 contains some info that I wanted to appear in a data grid view in form3, I searched online how to do it, so am not really that well-versed or fully understand the changes and or codes I wrote, as long as it worked. The problem now is that buttons from other forms 1 & 2 that supposedly hides and or shows other forms, have errors, it's a project and I would greatly appreciate your help, thx.

*form1 (error 1, in bold)*

```
Private Sub Button1_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles 
gin.Click
    Dim nun As String = "apple"
    Dim pw As Single = 7

    
    Dim name As String
    
    Dim wd As Double
   

    name = name.Text
    wd = word.Text
   
    If (name = nun And wd = pw) Then
        Me.Hide()
        **try**.Show() ' error here
    Else
        
        MsgBox("Denied", vbOKOnly + MsgBoxStyle.Critical, "TRY AGAIN")       End If

End Sub
```

*form2 (code for data grid view)*

```vb
Private Sub btnSave_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles 
    Save.Click

    view.dgvView.CurrentRow.Cells(1).Value = Id.Text
    view.dgvView.CurrentRow.Cells(2).Value = fruit.Text
    view.dgvView.CurrentRow.Cells(3).Value = veggie.Text
    view.dgvView.CurrentRow.Cells(4).Value = pasta.Text
    view.dgvView.CurrentRow.Cells(5).Value = drink.Text
End Sub
```

*form 3 (where error 2 is, the one in bold and the code above is the code that I don't fully understand )*

```vb
Public Class sky
    Private Sub dgvView_CellContentClick(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As 
    System.Windows.Forms.DataGridViewCellEventArgs) Handles sky.CellContentClick
        If e.ColumnIndex = 1 Then
            Dim entry As New sky(Me)
            entry.ShowInTaskbar = False
            entry.ShowDialog()
        End If
    End Sub

    Private Sub Button1_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles blue.Click
        Me.Close()
        **sky**.Show()

    End Sub
End Class
```

Comment: Forms are just classes. You create instances and assign the reference to variables just like any other class. The one difference is VB.Net gives you a default instance of each form, with the same name as the class type. But this is only the default behavior; it's possible to set a project to _not_ create these instances. It seems that _might_ be what happened here.

Comment: what is frmEntry supposed to do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`frmEntry` is not a variable, it is a type (a class name). You can use the variable `entry` created with `Dim entry As New frmEntry(Me)` to access the form object. But since this variable is a local variable, it is only accessible inside of the Sub that declared it. Declare it on the class level (outside of the Subs), so that other Subs can access it.

```vb
Public Class frmView
    Dim entry As frmEntry ' <===== declare here

    Private Sub FirstSub()
        entry = New frmEntry(Me)  ' <==== Create and assign here
        entry.ShowInTaskbar = False
        entry.Show()
    End Sub

    Private Sub SecondSub()
        entry.Close() ' <=== Reference it from somewhere else
    End Sub
End Class
```

Note that a class (and therefore also a Form) is a reference type. Other than a value type like `Integer`, a variable of a reference type does not store the object it is assigned, but a reference to this object. See the difference:

```vb
Dim a, b As Integer
Dim f1, f2 As frmTest

a = 5
b = a
b = 10
' Now a = 5 and b = 10

f1 = new frmTest()
f1.Text = "Test 1"
f2 = f1
f2.Text = "Test 2"
' Now f1.Text = "Test 2" and f2.Text = "Test 2" because there is only one Form
' object referenced by the two variables.
```